# Unable to classify topics using LDA trained model

Tags: python, nlp, lda

I have created a LDA model using Gensim, for which I first iterated from num_topics in range 3 to 10, and based on pyLDAvis plots, chose n = 3 in final lda model.

```
import glob
import sys
sys.path.append('/Users/tcssig/Documents/NLP_code_base/Doc_Similarity')
import normalization
from gensim.models.coherencemodel import CoherenceModel
datalist = []

for filename in glob.iglob('/Users/tcssig/Documents/Speech_text_files/*.*'):
    text = open(filename).readlines()
    text = normalization.normalize_corpus(text, only_text_chars=True, tokenize=True)
    datalist.append(text)

datalist = [datalist[i][0] for i in range(len(datalist))]

from gensim import models,corpora
import spacy
dictionary = corpora.Dictionary(datalist)
num_topics = 3
Lda = models.LdaMulticore

#lda= Lda(doc_term_matrix, num_topics=num_topics,id2word = dictionary, passes=20,chunksize=2000,random_state=3)

doc_term_matrix = [dictionary.doc2bow(doc) for doc in datalist]

dictionary = corpora.Dictionary(datalist)
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd
import spacy
import re
from tqdm._tqdm_notebook import tqdm_notebook,tnrange,tqdm
from collections import Counter,OrderedDict
from gensim import models,corpora
from gensim.summarization import summarize,keywords
import warnings
import pyLDAvis.gensim
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

Lda = models.LdaMulticore
coherenceList_umass = []
coherenceList_cv = []
num_topics_list = np.arange(3,10)
for num_topics in tqdm(num_topics_list):
    lda= Lda(doc_term_matrix, num_topics=num_topics,id2word = dictionary, passes=20,chunksize=4000,random_state=43)
    cm = CoherenceModel(model=lda, corpus=doc_term_matrix, dictionary=dictionary, coherence='u_mass')
    coherenceList_umass.append(cm.get_coherence())
    cm_cv = CoherenceModel(model=lda, corpus=doc_term_matrix, texts=datalist, dictionary=dictionary, coherence='c_v')
    coherenceList_cv.append(cm_cv.get_coherence())
    vis = pyLDAvis.gensim.prepare(lda, doc_term_matrix, dictionary)
    pyLDAvis.save_html(vis,'pyLDAvis_%d.html' %num_topics)


plotData = pd.DataFrame({'Number of topics':num_topics_list,'CoherenceScore':coherenceList_umass})
f,ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,6))
sns.set_style("darkgrid")
sns.pointplot(x='Number of topics',y= 'CoherenceScore',data=plotData)
plt.axhline(y=-3.9)
plt.title('Topic coherence')
plt.savefig('Topic coherence plot.png')

#################################################################
#################################################################

lda_final= Lda(doc_term_matrix, num_topics=3,id2word = dictionary, passes=20,chunksize=4000,random_state=43)

lda_final.save('lda_final')

dictionary.save('dictionary')

corpora.MmCorpus.serialize('doc_term_matrix.mm', doc_term_matrix)


a = lda_final.show_topics(num_topics=3,formatted=False,num_words=10)
b = lda_final.top_topics(doc_term_matrix,dictionary=dictionary,topn=10)


topic2wordb = {}
topic2csb = {}
topic2worda = {}
topic2csa = {}
num_topics =lda_final.num_topics
cnt =1

for ws in b:
    wset = set(w[1] for w in ws[0])
    topic2wordb[cnt] = wset
    topic2csb[cnt] = ws[1]
    cnt +=1

for ws in a:
    wset = set(w[0]for w in ws[1])
    topic2worda[ws[0]+1] = wset

for i in range(1,num_topics+1):
    for j in range(1,num_topics+1):  
        if topic2worda[i].intersection(topic2wordb[j])==topic2worda[i]:
            topic2csa[i] = topic2csb[j]

print('the final data block')
finalData = pd.DataFrame([],columns=['Topic','words'])
finalData['Topic']=topic2worda.keys()
finalData['Topic'] = finalData['Topic'].apply(lambda x: 'Topic'+str(x))
finalData['words']=topic2worda.values()
finalData['cs'] = topic2csa.values()
finalData.sort_values(by='cs',ascending=False,inplace=True)
finalData.to_csv('CoherenceScore.csv')
print(finalData)
```

Now i have the trained model with me, but I want to know how I use the model on the docs used for training and also on new unseen document to assign the topic

I'm using the below code to do this but getting the error as below :

```
unseen_document = 'How a Pentagon deal became an identity crisis for Google'

text = normalization.normalize_corpus(unseen_document, only_text_chars=True, tokenize=True)

bow_vector = dictionary.doc2bow(text)

corpora.MmCorpus.serialize('x.bow_vector', bow_vector)

corpus = [dictionary.doc2bow(text)]

x = lda_final[corpus]
```

Error Message :

```
    Topic                                              words        cs
2  Topic3  {senator, people, power, home, year, believe, ... -0.175486
1  Topic2  {friend, place, love, play, general, house, ye... -0.318839
0  Topic1  {money, doe, fucking, play, love, people, worl... -1.360688

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "LDA_test.py", line 141, in <module>
    corpus = [dictionary.doc2bow(text)]
  File "/Users/tcssig/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gensim/corpora/dictionary.py", line 250, in doc2bow
    counter[w if isinstance(w, unicode) else unicode(w, 'utf-8')] += 1
TypeError: coercing to str: need a bytes-like object, list found
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this line

```
corpus = [dictionary.doc2bow(text)]
```

You are creating a list of BOW vectors. You need to lookup those vectors, not the list, e.g.

```
for v in corpus:
    print(lda_final[v])
```

Will show the topic probability distribution for a document.

See the [gensim docs](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/ldamodel.html)